# How can you factor $x^4-6x^3+8x^2+2x-1?$

Tags: functions, factoring

The original question is:

Solve this equation for x:

$$(x^2-3x+1)^2-3(x^2-3x+1)+1=x$$

I expanded and simplified it to get
$$x^4-6x^3+8x^2+2x-1=0$$

Since neither -1 nor 1 are factors, it appears that the roots will be fractional. How can I proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: None of the roots can be fractional.  They will have to be either complex or irrational.

Comment: Are you saying that the equation has no real solutions?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the equation has no rational solutions.

Comment: Actually it has at least **two** real solutions because the value of the corresponding polynomial is $-1$ for $x=0$ and positive for large $\pm x$

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%28x%5E4+-+6x%5E3+%2B+8x%5E2+%2B2x-1%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that initial equation have following form:
$$f(f(x))=x$$
where $f(x) = x^2 -3x+1$

So roots of $f(x)=x$ equation will be roots of your initial equation. Solve this quadratic equation and you will get 2 roots. Other 2 roots you can get from 4-degree polynom factorization.

Comment: What does that mean to be in the form of f(f(x))=x? I still don't understand why x^2-3x+1 is a root.

Comment: Let $x$ be root $x^2-3x+1=x$ equation. This means that you can substitute $x^2-3x+1$ with $x \Rightarrow (x^2-3x+1)^2-3(x^2-3x+1)+1 = x^2-3x+1=x$. This means that $x$ is root of your initial equation

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$f(x)=x^2(x-3)^2-(x-1)^2$

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with that hint because I only learned to solve equations once they are completely factored.

Comment: Do you know about the difference of two squares?

Comment: Yes! I didn't see that. Let me see if I can solve that now.

Comment: Okay, I understand how to solve it given your hint. But how did you put the equation in that form?

Comment: I noticed the first three terms are close to $169=13^2$.  I would have forgotten that and moved on, but it turned out that the quartic looks like $16900-121=130^2-11^2$, which works.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x^2 -3x + 1$

Note that the original equation is in the form $f(x)^2 - 3f(x) + 1 = x$, and the LHS is equivalent to $f(f(x))$.

So you know that the required roots are the roots of $f(f(x)) = x$.

Apply the inverse function to both sides to get $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

Graphically, the inverse function is formed by reflecting the function in the line of identity $y = x$. This implies that the two points of intersection between $y=f(x)$ and $y=x$ will give the required roots.

So all you have to solve is $x^2 - 3x + 1 = x$ or $x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$.

(Of course, it's strictly improper to speak of an inverse function here, since the quadratic is not bijective. If you wanted to be rigorous, you could split the domain up to make the same argument).

Comment: Where does X^2-4x+1=0 come from?

Comment: @Jonathan Just a rearrangement of $x^2 - 3x + 1 = x$.

Comment: Actually $f$ doesn't have inverse function since it's not injective.

Comment: @hvedrung I made the edit (before your comment actually). The argument can be made rigorous by considering the half-domains separately.